# vue js error:" For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option." when recursively create table

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I create a dynamic HTML table by vue js which get data from server. The data includes 'columns', which is a Array with server objects including the table header(key is title), 'q', is the value type of each column generated from database table column name, 'content", the value display method. e.g content='content":'', the cell will display like ''.

HTML Part

```
   <div id="app3">

        <table  class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" v-for="c in columns" v-text="c.title"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <vue-cell:rows="rows" :columns="columns">
                </vue-row>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Vue js part

```
<script>
var columns =[
      {'q': "id",
      'title': 'id',
      'content":'<input type="checkbox">'

      },
      {'q': "type",
      'title': 'Type',
       'content":''
      },


]

var rows=[
      {'id': 1,
       'type':"Server",
      },
      {'id': 2,
       'type':"PC",
      },

]
```

create component to loop rows and column

```
Vue.component('vue-cell', {
         name:'inputBox',
         props: {
             rows: Array,
             columns: Array,
         },

         render: function (createElement) {
             var self = this
             return createElement('tr', self.rows.map(function(row) {
                 return createElement('td', self.columns.map(function(column) {
                      // comlum.q = id or type ...
                      // column['content'] = <input type="checkbox"> 
                      //assign row.id as defalut value
                      if (column['content'].includes('checkbox')) {
                          return createElement('input', {
                              attrs: {
                                 type: "checkbox",
                              },
                              domProps: {
                                  // column.q may not be 'id' maybe type
                                  // get the value of type or id in a row.
                                  value:  row[column.q],
                              }
                          })
                      } else {
                           return row[column.q];}
                 }))
         }))


         },
     })
```

Create a new Vue

```
    new Vue ({
        data: function() {
            return {
                columns: [],
                rows:[],
            }

        },
        created: function() {
             var self = this;
             axios.("/web/asset-json.html").then(function (response) {
               self.columns = [...response.data.columns];
               self.rows  = [...response.data.rows]
})
}

})
</script>
```

Comment: Your single, individual component, cannot return several parent components. Consider using `<tr is="vue-cell" :columns="columns" v-for="(row, index) in rows" :key="index"></tr>` and separate out the rendering of these rows on an individual basis. [scroll to the bottom of the documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats)

Comment: When using a loop (i.e. `self.columns.map(...)`) you need to provide a unique `key` value for each generated root element. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth